# React order of execution

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a code that sets a state of current user logged in, and i want to do something if the user is logged in, but the User information doesnt gets updated in order. I cannot explain it right, so ill right the code below.

```
 const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()


    try {
        const user = await signInAuthUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email,
            password
        );
        const test = await setCurrentUser(user)
        console.log(currentUser)
        currentUser ? setToggleSuccess(true) : setToggleSuccess(false)
        resetFormFields();
        console.log(currentUser)
    } catch (error) {
```

the console.log's return 'null', but they are below the setCurrentUser. How to make the setCurrentUser get triggered before the console.logs?

Answer (score 1):

setCurrentUser is definitely an async function but even if you add await while calling it, the state won't be updated instantaneously. You will get the changes in useEffect only. I will suggest you to use the variable user in the function defined instead of using "currentUser".

Also, if your resetFormFields uses currentUser then it should be called inside useEffect.

Note:- I am assuming that the current user is a react state and setCurrentUser is used to update the state.

Comment: that works fine man :)))))) tysm